# Windows 10 multi options sorting

Tags: windows-10, sorting, date, file-attributes

I'd like to know if there is a feature in Windows 10 that allows the user to sort files using multiple attributes: I have folders full of photos taken with different cameras that show the date they were taken as different attributes; dates could be stored as

- last Modified
- last Acquisition
- last Creation

I'd like to sort them using some kind of algorithm that checks if the default attributes it should be sorted by exists for the current file, and if it doesn't, another attributes will be used for that file as default, like

```
sortFolderWithOptions(sortAttribute1,sortAttribute2,...) {

/* every file gets a default attributes to be sorted by */
arraySortAttributes = Array(Folder.fileLenght).fill(sortAttribute1);

  for(i = 0, i < Folder.fileLenght, i++) {
    /* but if the default sort attribute for this file is missing, the next sort attribute is used instead, for this file */
    if(Folder.file[i].sortAttribute1 == null) arraySortAttributes[i] = sortAttribute2;
  }
  /* using default Windows Folder sorting algorithm */
  defaultWndowsSortFolder(arraySortType);
} 


sortFolderWithOptions(lastAcquisition,lastCreated)
```

If nothing like this exist for Windows, does Linux have any similiar feature? Or is there a way to make this sort in some programming language or change file data quickly for a large amount of files (not manually)?

Comment: It a poor question for SO. If you are talking about folder windows then sort by your least sort option and sort up to your most favoured. So by last Creation, last Acquisition, and then Last Modified.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but you can <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click the categories in Windows!

I just used this to sort files by: `FileType > Owner > ModifiedDate`